# Is possible to create global array?

Tags: java, android

I need to fill data in 50 instances of DataPack.class let's say in class A, but I need to read out that data in some class B. Class DataPack looks like this:

```
public class DataPack {
    int fNumber;
    int dateTime;
    int Year, fMonth, fDay;
    int fTimeHours, fTimeMin, fTimeSec;
    int fSize;
    char[] name = new char[18];
    char[] surname = new char[18];
}
```

In class A I would create DataPack[] mDataPack = new DataPack[50]; and then fill data in each array member. But for reading in class B, this data array will need to be global. 
 Is this possible to solve this in that way? Or exists better solutions?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Maybe just implement a callback interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a `ClassicSingleton.java` class like below and use that any of function or data member in any of class.

### How to make Singleton Class ?

```
public class ClassicSingleton {

   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   public ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>(); // Member

   protected ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
   public String getName()
   {
   String myName="Chintan Khetiya";
   return myName;
   }

   public ArrayList<String> getNameformarray() {
     name.add("Android");
     name.add("IPhone");
     name.add("Windows");
     return name;

    }

}
```

### How to use function and member of the Singleton class ?

```
ClassicSingleton CS= new ClassicSingleton();
CS.getInstance();
String myName=CS.getname(); // Output will be >> Chintan Khetiya
String like=CS.getNameformarray().get(1); // Output will be >> Android
```

same way you can use the data member here as publicly by static reference of object.

This is best ans stranded way to use.

Comment: I tried this, I created member of singleton class: DataPack[] mDataPacks = new DataPack[50]; But when I am trying to access for example, CS.mDataPacks[1].fNumber I get NullPointersException, so it looks like mDataPacks is not instantiate correct..any solution?

Comment: @anze87 let me know if you have still issue with it.and accept it if it is okay for you.

Comment: It's not working that way: ClassicSingleton CS= new ClassicSingleton(); ClassicSingleton CS; CS.getInstance(); is fine. I can't access to array of DataPack, because I get NulPointers Exception.

Comment: @anze87 did you check my updated code ? in above comment you have create  two times obj so might be issue , i checked my code its working

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I didn't create new instances for DataPack. I add mDataPacks = new DataPack[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   mDataPacks[i] = new DataPack(); It's working now. 
     }

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

- Make a `BaseActivity` extending `Activity`
- Extend your other activities to `BaseActivity`
- Create `DataPack` array instance in `BaseActivity`
- When saving DataPack details, save it in `BaseActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a special class called the Application class. If you declare any variable there it can be accessed through out your application. Its like a global singleton.

```
  public class DataPack {
  int fNumber;
  int dateTime;
  int Year, fMonth, fDay;
  int fTimeHours, fTimeMin, fTimeSec;
  int fSize;
  char[] name = new char[18];
  char[] surname = new char[18];
  }
  public class A extends Application 
  {     
   DataPack[] mDataPack = new DataPack[50];
  }
```

Now go to manifest and make the following change:

```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="com.yourAppName.DataPack">
```

Then you can go to any activity and use this global singleton like:

```
  DataPack pack = (DataPack)getApplication();
  //get the array using <pack.mDataPack> in a loop.
```

Advantages of using a singleton:
*The application state remains the same even if there is a change in screen orientation.

Comment: But I need 50 packs...how is that with singleton?

Comment: create 50 packs, store them in an array of objects... and then store that array of object in the global singleton.